# "SparkFun SAMD21 Mini Breakout" 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope

Tags: serial, samd21g

I recently switched computers and installed Arduino IDE, Added SAMD21 to the boards manager and installed drivers.

My sketch previously ran on my laptop with no problems.  Now when I try to compile for the SAMD21 Mini, I get a 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope error.

If I try to compile it for Mega, there are no problems.

I have tried sample code with Serial1 for SAMD21 and it compiled and uploaded with no problems.

Comment: The samd21g serial options are more configurable than for an AVR.  Much of this is left to the variant definition.  So which board do you have selected?

Comment: I selected "SparkFun SAMD21 Mini Breakout".  I got it working see below :)

Comment: Given that you're now liable to be the only person to answer the question, you may want to just edit the question and answer to make a good read for whomever comes across it in the future.  E.g. the question doesn't mention that you're not working in an .ino file.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh, I figured it out.  I had to add `#include "Arduino.h"` to the .cpp file.